# Server-client cprogramming handle multiple connection requests

Tags: c, connection, client

Want to make a server-client connection. I want to send data of 2 or more clients to the server. The server needs to collect al this data and write it to database. The problem is, how to work with fork(), getppid? getpid? wait()? How to avoid zombies etc.

```
int main( void ) 
{
  pid_t client_pid;
  pid_t wait(int *status);


  Socket server, client; 
  int bytes; 

  // open server socket 
  server = tcp_passive_open( PORT ); 

  while( 1 ) {     
    client = tcp_wait_for_connection( server ); 

    //create new process
    client_pid = fork();  
    printf("%d",client_pid); 
    //client must have id 
    if(client_pid >= 0){ 
    if(client_pid > 0){        //server



    }else{                //client

        bytes = tcp_receive( client, buffer, BUFSIZE);  
            printf("received message of %d bytes: %s\n", bytes, buffer); 

        // echo msg back to client 
        char buffer[] = "Send data ....put data here"; 
            tcp_send( client, (void*)buffer, bytes); 

            //sleep(1);    /* to allow socket to drain */ 
            tcp_close( &client );

    }
     }  
  }
  tcp_close( &server ); 
  return 0; 
}
```

For the client i wrote this:

```
#define BUFSIZE 1024
#define SERVER_IP "127.0.0.1"
#define PORT 1234

unsigned char buffer[BUFSIZE];

int main( void ) {
  Socket client;
  int ret;
  char msg[] = "Hello there! Anyone?";

  // open TCP connection to the server; server is listening to SERVER_IP and PORT
  client = tcp_active_open( PORT, SERVER_IP );

  // send msg to server
  tcp_send( client, (void *)msg, strlen(msg)+1 );

  // get reply from server
  printf("\nanswer from server: ");
  while ( (ret = tcp_receive (client, buffer, BUFSIZE)) > 0 ) {
     printf("%s", buffer);
  }
  printf("\n");  

  // exit
  tcp_close( &client );
  return 1;
}
```

Can somebody help me out? Know any good tutorial how to work with this processes , threads , etc?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) fork a procedure to wait for client connection;

b) wait for zombie process in the main loop;

c) check [How does fork() return for child process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562602/how-does-fork-return-for-child-process/2562620#2562620) for detailed usage of fork.

Comment: How to wait for client connection? Because when i start up the client, there also start a process in the server. So i need to put the process id's & data in an array? And then finish every process in the array? Also need to check if the process have any childs? But i'm stuck at a.

Comment: @user1209154 server and client are different process, right? Then we only need to take care of server processes. We use wait() in the main loop to take care of zombie child processes.

Comment: @user1209154 Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2270925/how-does-one-use-the-wait-function-when-forking-multiple-processes

Comment: I don't know how to start with the fork? Do i need to create for client & server a fork? And do i need to collect die pid & data in an array or struct pointer?

Comment: @user1209154 BTW, where does the problem exist, client or server?

Comment: i can send text with multiple clients, doens anyone now a good topic how to send files from client -> server?